# Executing a POST command in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm looking to execute the following POST command in powershell, passing in the body as the parameter

```
$request = Invoke-Restmethod -TimeoutSec 600 -URI 'http://<servername>:5000/api/test/test' -Method POST -Body "aum_date_str:2020-09-16" -ContentType "application/json"
```

but it fails with an invalid json format error ...

```
Invoke-Restmethod : {
  "type": "about:blank",
  "title": "Bad Request",
  "detail": "Request body is not valid JSON",
  "status": 400
}
```

I have verified the json format and it's fine.  Any ideas why this error is occurring?

Comment: Try `$request = Invoke-Restmethod -TimeoutSec 600 -URI 'http://<servername>:5000/api/test/test' -Method POST -Body '{"aum_date_str":"2020-09-16"}' -ContentType "application/json"`

Comment: Sorry for the delay but thanks very much.  I made a few tweaks and got it working after looking at the previous answer that Kyle posted.

Answer (score 0):

Your `-Body`-parameter is not a JSON. Correct JSON-document must begins and ends with braces (`{}`) and field name and value must be in quotes. Value may be without quotes if it is integer or boolean.

Try to send this: `{"aum_date_str":"2020-09-16"}`

More about JSON syntax you can read [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) or [here](https://medium.com/omarelgabrys-blog/json-in-a-nutshell-7d638dfea7cc)

Comment: Same error with this as well unfortunately.

Comment: I've also added  $param = "aum_date_str:$Date" (with the $Date variable being 2020-09-16), and then added ($param|ConvertTo-Json) to the request, but now I'm getting an error saying the parameter I'm using "is not of type object"

Comment: @BobbyS, check updated version. I've add quotes to JSON field and value

Comment: Sorry for the delay but thanks very much.  I made a few tweaks and got it working after looking at the previous answer that Kyle posted.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should add {}

> $request = Invoke-Restmethod -TimeoutSec 600 -URI 'http://:5000/api/test/test' -Method POST -Body "{aum_date_str:2020-09-16}" -ContentType "application/json"

Comment: Hi!  I tried this but still getting the same error

Comment: Sorry for the delay but thanks very much.  I made a few tweaks and got it working after looking at the previous answer that Kyle posted.

Comment: You will need the quotes to make the json valid

$json = @"
{
    "aum_date_str": 2020-09-16
}
"@

$request = Invoke-Restmethod -TimeoutSec 600 -URI 'http://<servername>:5000/api/test/test' -Method POST -Body $json -ContentType "application/json"

Comment: '{"aum_date_str": 2020-09-16}' or "{`"aum_date_str`": 2020-09-16}" should work as well